# mysql count some column's values in one column

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have that MySQL table:

```
table
| ID | col1 | col2 | col 3|
  1      1      0      1
  2      0      1      1
  3      1      1      1
```

how to count all col1, col2, col3 in one column to each row like this?

```
table
| ID | colnew |
  1      2      
  2      2    
  3      3
```

Thx.

Comment: Do you want the *count* or the *sum*? Your example is ambiguous, all columns have `1` and you do not clarify why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, col1 + col2 + col3 AS colnew FROM my_table
```